# Convert python date format (%Y) to java (yyyy)

Tags: python

I have a bunch of time formats in the following format:

```
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Is there a quick way or a library to convert these to:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

My current method to do so is using a string replace, but perhaps I'll be missing some edge cases. The possible formatters I have are:

```
%d %b %Y %y %H %M %S %p %f %m %d %z %A
```

An example would be:

```
format.replace('%Y', 'yyyy')
```

And on and on...

Comment: What do you want to convert? The occurences of the string `'%Y'` to the string `'yyyy'` within a string `'%Y ...'`? You say you have multiple time *formats*. Can you give more examples?

Comment: May I ask the purpose of this?

Comment: @Jab: Not OP, but I for example need this to convert my known pandas datetime formats (Python style) into PySpark datetime formats, which use java...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way would be to use the `%` format as a template and then provide a mapping, e.g.:

```
In []:
from string import Template
mapping = {'Y': 'yyyy', 'm': 'MM', 'd': 'dd', 'H': 'HH', 'M': 'mm', 'S': 'ss'}
Template("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S".replace('%', '$')).substitute(**mapping)

Out[]:
'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

Instead of doing `str.replace()` you can change the template delimiter by subclassing `Template`, e.g.:

```
In []:
class MyTemplate(Template):
    delimiter = '%'

MyTemplate("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").substitute(**mapping)

Out[]:
'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

To know more about % format : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Comment: I still don't understand the question, though.

Comment: I've assumed the OP is trying to move from some python date format strings to java format strings (`SimpleDataFormat()`) and is looking to automate it.

Comment: @AChampion cool, thank you for the response and the suggestion of using a template over string replace.

Comment: @cs95: Assume you have a .csv table that you want to import, and the dates are in a bunch of formats... e.g. `12.11.2018` and `2017-25-01`. You know these formats (e.g. `%d.%m.%Y`) Python-style, but the import asks for Java-style descriptions of the datetime formatting... like pyspark does, for example.

Comment: I was thinking of regex solution, but this is a great answer...

Comment: @AChampion I've the exact same problem but the other way around. I need to move from yyyy to %Y. Any ideas?

Comment: Without a marker like `%` then the above template approach will not work. You may want to look into the `re` module.