# Convert Java date format (yyyy) to Python (%Y)

Tags: python, date, format, strftime

I'm getting  Java date format strings (yyyymmdd) as input. I need to convert them to Python-based format (%Y%m%d) or just use these to get the current date in that format in Python. e.g. I want to achieve the following in Python:

```
print(current_time.strftime('yyyymmdd')
```

Result:

```
20210426
```

[Convert python date format (%Y) to java (yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120928/convert-python-date-format-y-to-java-yyyy)
Similar question but its the other way around and I can't use Template like this since there is no delimiter

Comment: are you getting the formatting strings or the actual dates as input?

Comment: I'm getting the formatting strings as input. I need to use them to convert a datetime object into the string format specified by the input, however, the format is Java based (yyyymmdd) whereas the strftime requires (%Y%m%d %h).

Comment: I don’t think it’s realistic to make the conversion for every possible Java date format string, but handling the 95 % most popular ones should be doable.

Comment: See answer [here - Convert python date format (%Y) to java (yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120928/convert-python-date-format-y-to-java-yyyy)

Comment: @orak did you find a way to achieve that. I'm dealing with the same issue as receiving dates in a csv file with the java data associated. And need to find a way to convert that format tp a python datetime format

Comment: @jledru I used the following explicit statement since I knew which formats would be coming. Couldn't find a generic solution catering all use cases:  
                   python_format = java_format.replace('yyyy', '%Y').replace('yy', '%y').replace('MM', '%m').replace(
                        'dd', '%d').replace('hh', '%H')

Comment: @jledru try using the https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ package which handles most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Here's how to achieve the same output with python3 using datetime module:

```
import datetime

today_date_obj = datetime.date.today()
formatted_date_string = str(today_date_obj.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

print(formatted_date_string)
```

Dates in python are objects. To convert your date to string, use str().